# Shared Preferences empty after switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I've got a really weird problem with my shared preferences. I'm using them to store the user-ID, different settings and so on. I'm using an activity which switches fragments if a user has clicked an item in my menu (I'm using [Menu-Drawer](http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/)).

After every login I store the user profile. This works perfect. After doing this I can restart the app, kill it from the memory, I can even restart my device and my values are still stored. But when I switch the fragment, e.g I'm in the home view and click "about app" in the menu, everything is gone. My values are empty.

Where it gets even weirder: If I force the activity to reload the fragment by selecting the home-item while I'm already in the home view, it's still stored. Only if I replace it with a different type of fragment everything is lost.

I don't have any idea why the app behaves like this. It's all in the same activity with the same context. I'm always using getActivity to get my context inside the fragment.

Here's a simplified snippet of my code to store it.

```
public static void storeUserProfile(Context context, LoginEvent event, String userId, String emailAddress, String passwordHash) {

    SharedPreferences userPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
    editor.clear();

    editor.putString("username", event.userName);
    editor.putString("id", userId);
    editor.putString("email", emailAddress);

    editor.commit();
}
```

This is how I switch my fragments:

```
HomeFeedFragment fragment = new HomeFeedFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Are you always using AppConfig.USER_PREFS for your sharedprefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the fast responses! I've found the error myself. For the about view, I'm loading an html file which will be stored in shared preferences too. I haven't thought about the fact that sharedpreferences are just an xml file so I think that the html string made the xml file invalid.

I've noticed that `my prefs.getString(key, defaultValue)` weren't returning the defaultValue, they were returning an empty String. So I've removed the html storing and do this in a different way.

But thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 5):

Try this snippet, it can be accessed from all activities/ fragments in your app.

Declare these methods first..

```
public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    }

public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}
```

Then call this when you want to put a pref:

```
putPref("myKey", "mystring", getApplicationContext());
```

call this when you want to get a pref:

```
 getPref("myKey", getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: please not put code "random" because not work, and spend time from all users of Stack!

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Using fragments, does not work with `getSharedPreferences()` only with 
`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (getActivity ());`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i solved by changing the key string of my **sharedpreferences**

I was using :

```
SharedPreferences userPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MuslimActive", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I changed with :

```
SharedPreferences userPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("muslim_active", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Anything past 2.3 and MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is disable by default, and if multiple instances of the same SharedPreferences exist MODE_MULTI_PROCESS will need to be set.

Try:

```
getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Also, make sure you are consistently using AppConfig.USER_PREFS in your method calls.